# Data domain data pull using PowerShell to SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh, emc

I'm currently working on a Powershell script that will run on a server and ssh to a text list of data domains on a weekly/monthly basis. From this list, it will loop through each, connecting and running a command to grab information from each DD. I have no experience with Powershell prior, and my knowledge is limited to university-education levels of Linux and standard commands.

The script was based off the following:

> http://findnevilleat.blogspot.ca/2013/12/using-powershell-to-check-data-domains.html

I'm currently trying to modify the script to meet my needs but have been stuck on the output. 
Currently I can ssh into each data domain and pull out data with "df" and post-comp but to grab other data is still a mystery to me.(There aren't alot of sources even on the EMC site).

To summarize, I am wondering if anyone has any idea how to grab more information from the following commands:

- system - show all/ show modelno/ show hardware/ show stats
- filesys -  show space

Here is a basic overview of my script so far: ( I apologize for the mess, I could only do so much editing)

> ```
>           WriteLog "Checking Data Domain Available Space"
>           $includeList="Cleanable GiB|--------|/data: post-comp" #Data domain format command to print
>           $DB = Get-Content $answerfile #inputstream from file
>
>
>           foreach ($Data in $DB){ ##bracket required on same line for foreach / foreach for iteration through data domains
>               $hostname = $Data.Trim() #gets host name without new line character for the SSH command.
>
>                 #~~~~~~~~~ Password Set up ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                 if($hostname -eq "139.12.34.56" -Or $hostname -eq 
>  "10.123.11.108") ##if hostname is one of the selected, change password
>  to correct 
>                 {
>                 $passwd = "12345PASS"
>                 }
>                 else #all other servers require this secondary password
>                 {
>                 $passwd = "54321PASS" 
>                 }
>                 #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                 # Options: Hardcoded(current) / Read write from file.
>                 # With more passwords: Hardcoded = Switch
>                 #                      ReadWrite = Add to list
>
>
>                 #~~~~~~~~~~  SSH command and exe command Set up Process~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                 $exe = "CMD" #Launch CMD for use
>
>
>               $command = "/C $plinkcommand $user@$Data -pw ""$passwd"" df" #ssh command
>               $Data > 
>                 #$command2 = "/C $plinkcommand $user@$Data -pw ""$passwd"" System show preformance" #ETC
>                 #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                 # Currently supporting structure(below) to run other commands
>                 # Commands to be added: System  - (show all, show modelno, show compression, show hardware, show stats)    
>                 #                       Filesys - Show space
>                 #                       Possibly more to be added at a later time
>
>
>                 #~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Navigation of directories in host computer ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                 invoke-expression "cd /" #Change directory to Root          
>                 invoke-expression "cd /users/kevindong/documents/powershellscripts" #change directory to
>                 plink location
>                 #Set up command to navigate to plink (requires set up dependedant on computer)
>                 #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                 # Possible update to "invoke-expression", and possible specific targeted location of operating file directory
>
>                 #~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Execution of SSH data grab commands ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>               $outputcontents = &$exe $command ##ssh connect execution + "df" command
>
>               if ($outputcontents -ne "") #if SSH is not null
>               {
>
>                   $outputcontents | ForEach-Object { #foreach requires bracket on same line
>                        if ($_ -match $includeList) { WriteLog $_ }  #run data collection
>
>                     #add commands here and write log them    
>                     }
>               }
>                 #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>           }
> ```

Thank you to anyone who took/takes a look into my problem. I appreciate it.